# making Console::WriteLine(x) in the same line when looped in CLR console C++

Tags: console, c++-cli, clr

I'm trying to create a pascal triangle using stdafx.h.
I come to a problem when trying to put a `Console::WriteLine(x)` using a loop but wanting it in the same line

*I "translated" this from a Iostream C++ empty project*

```
#include "stdafx.h"


using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{ 
int k, i, x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
Console::WriteLine(L"Number of Rows : ");
String^ strabx = Console::ReadLine();
int n = int::Parse(strabx); //the number of rows
d = 0;
g = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= (n - 1); i++) // i adalah baris 
{
    for (a = (n - i); a >= 1; a--) {
        Console::WriteLine("   ");
    }
    x = 1;
    b = 0;

    e = 0;
    f = 0;
    k = 0;
    do
    {
        f = f + x;

        Console::WriteLine("  " + x + "  ");    //my problem lies here
        x = x * (i - k) / (k + 1);

        b = b + 1; 
        k++;
    } while (k <= i);


    c = b;    
    d = d + c;  
    g = f + g;   
    Console::WriteLine();
}
Console::WriteLine("digit count " + d + "\n");
Console::WriteLine("sums of the number : " + g);

Console::ReadLine();
Console::WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: `stdafx.h` is the name of the precompiled header automatically generated for a Visual Studio project. It has nothing to do with generating a Pascal's triangle. I think maybe you mean a .NET project.

Comment: Anyway you have two main options: (1) use a routine like `Console::Write`, if there is one (I think I remember that there is), or (2) collect your output line in a string and output it when it's complete.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Console::Write()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
Console::Write("  " + x + "  ");
```